# cifs mount failed with code -2

Tags: 18.04, mount, cifs

I'm new to ubuntu and Linux and doing my best to learn. My problem is as follows:

I am trying to mount a shared folder from one 18.04.5 machine (a) to another 18.04.5 machine (b). The mount between (a on b) is successful however I have another machine (A) that I have done my very best to set up identically to (a) but when I mount (A on b) it fails.

The configuration of (a) and (A) are

- each have the newest cifs-utils (2:6.8-1ubuntu1.1)
- each have the newest  keyutils (1.5.9-9.2ubuntu2)
- each have the same /etc/samba/smb.conf configurations

ie.>>

```
[mymount]
path = /home/mypath
user = myusername
read only = no
```

In addition:

- the user on (a) and (A) are configured identically (ie. same groups)
- the shared folders on (a) and (A) are configured identically

The `/etc/fstab` file on (b) uses the same dialog to mount each share but the machine IP addresses change to point to (a) and (A)
ie.>>

```
//192.168.10.20/mymount /media/mountpoint_a cifs credentials=credentialspath,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,vers=3.0 0 0

//192.168.10.21/mymount /media/mountpoint_A cifs credentials=credentialspath,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,vers=3.0 0 0
```

Given the above can anyone point me toward a possible solution for the problem? For example is there a likely utility / dependency that I've missed between configuring machines (a) and (A)?

The "dmesg" errors for mounting (A on b) given are:

```
[  945.570887] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.10.21/mymount
[  945.571836] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[  945.571853] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

The verbose out says:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

The directories for mymount and mountpoint_A each exist and the mountpoint_a folder has the same credentials as mountpoint_A. Given that mountpoint_a works, I don't think it's a folder or permission problem.

I have read the following related posts but they have not provided working answers to this problem:

- [SMB cifs wont automout using vers=3.0 in Ubuntu Server 18.04LTS /etc/fstab while using credentials file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138203/smb-cifs-wont-automout-using-vers-3-0-in-ubuntu-server-18-04lts-etc-fstab-while)
- [cifs mount differences: mount command vs fstab entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292855/cifs-mount-differences-mount-command-vs-fstab-entry)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS : Mount CIFS On Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097805/ubuntu-18-04-lts-mount-cifs-on-boot)

Comment: @mook765 those are addressing two different machines (referred to as `a` and `A`) with supposedly identical setup on them. OP wants to mount these on `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration on machine A was missing Samba. Once installed everything worked.

> > 

apt-get install samba